# SocialEngine module doesn't output anything

Tags: php, module, socialengine

I have created a module which was downloaded from SocialEngine and uploaded there without making any changes to the source code.

The controller code:

```
// Controllers/IndexController.php
class Likecounter_IndexController extends Core_Controller_Action_Standard
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->someVar = 'someVal';
    }
}
```

The view code:
    // views/scripts/index/index.tpl
    Index for skeleton module: Likecounter

```
someVar : <?php echo $this->someVar; ?>
```

And the Bootstrap.php code:

```
// Root of Likecounter(module name) directory
class Likecounter_Bootstrap extends Engine_Application_Bootstrap_Abstract
{
}
```

BUT NOTHING OUTPUT :(
What's your guess? Why it doesn't print out anything?

Thanks

Comment: At least tell me your guess or ask some questions please.

Answer (score 0):

It will work on the link with /likecounter or whatever you set in manifest.php under routes.

Comment: In order to check that, could you help me what structure it has? I have copied this from user section:        'routes' => array(
 'user_general' => array(
  'route' => 'members/:action/*',
  'defaults' => array(
  'module' => 'user',
  'controller' => 'index',
  'action' => 'browse'
 ),
 'reqs' => array(
  'action' => '(home|browse)',
 )
),    How can I change them to be fixed with mine. Thanks

Comment: some this like this:

'routes' => array( 'likecounter_general' => array( 'route' => 'likecounter/:controller/:action/*', 'defaults' => array( 'module' => 'likecounter', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index' ), 'reqs' => array( 'action' => '(home|browse|index)') ),

Comment: I have gone to that page, but it returns 404 page

Answer (score 0):

Does your module include necessary files/folders such as `/application/modules/Likecounter/settings/manifest.php`? If so, can you check if your module is enabled in your package manager (it can be found on yoursite.com/install/manage)?

Next, you may place something like `echo "it works"; die();` right in `indexAction()` of your controller. Then when you visit `yoursite.com/likecounter` it should show you blank white page with "it works" text.

If not, you should check the end part of the log file which is in `/temporary/log/main.log`. Hope this helps.